# How to write permissions for the startup program in xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, permissions, cross-platform, startup

I want to write a program that will run automatically when the phone is switched on. I want to show notifications from this program on a daily basis at certain times. The user will set the timing of these notifications. I am registering this in the database with sqlite. And I have defined a broadcast receiver and service in the program I wrote for it. I am creating notifications using pending intent. So when the phone is turned off, the notifications that the user is generating are disappearing. My classes are like this:

Class BootCompleted: BroadcastReceiver

Class AlarmReceiver: BroadcastReceiver

Class AutoStartUp: Service

In my AndroidManifest, I made the following definitions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application android:label="myprogram">
    <receiver
      android:name=".ReminderService.BootCompleted"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".ReminderService.AutoStartUp">
    </service>
  </application>
```

As a result, when I installed this program on the phone and tried it, the problem occurred.
So when I create the notifications as a user and then switch the phone off and on, I get an error like 'the program stopped working'.
Why does this happen?

My BootCompleted class is extend BroadcastReceiver

```
    [BroadcastReceiver]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionBootCompleted })]
    public class BootCompleted : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            Log.Debug("BroadcastReceiverBoot", "BootCompleted");
            if (intent.Action.Equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"))
            {
                Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(AutoStartUp));
                context.StartService(serviceIntent);
            }
        }
    }
```

My AlarmReceiver class is extend BroadcastReceiver

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionBootCompleted })]
    public class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {

                var message = intent.GetStringExtra("message");
                var title = intent.GetStringExtra("title");

                var notIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
                notIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.ClearTask);
                var contentIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0, notIntent,
                    PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);
                var manager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(context);

                var style = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
                style.BigText(message);

                var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                                .SetContentIntent(contentIntent)
                                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon)
                                .SetContentTitle(title)
                                .SetContentText(message)
                                .SetStyle(style)
                                .SetAutoCancel(true);

                var notification = builder.Build();
                manager.Notify(DateTime.Now.Millisecond, notification);
        }
    }
```

My AutoStartUp class is extend Service

```
class AutoStartUp : Service
    {
        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            try
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "boot1", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                AndroidReminderService.BootRemind(DateTime.Now, "Boot Control", "Phone Opened!", DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute + 2, DateTime.Now.Second);
                Toast.MakeText(this, "boot2", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, e.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: hard to tell without complete code. It can crash everywhere...

Comment: I share the contents of classes as comments

Comment: That's all my code. I am writing this program cross-platform as well. This is the code I wrote in the complex android part.

Comment: How do I use this onstartcommand? What does it do?

Comment: You should read some docs about Android service. https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/fundamentals/service/create_a_simple_service/ Note [Service] attribute too. If you provide complete solution I might be able to help more. Without running it and finding where it crashes this is all I can do for you.

Comment: Are there any drawbacks when I define multiple receivers? @YuriS

Comment: No, shouldn't be. You can try to register receivers one by one and see what is happening (unless they talk to each other)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding them in your broadcastreceiver class

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionBootCompleted })]
class BroadcastReceiverBoot : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Log.Debug("BroadcastReceiverBoot", "Boot Completed ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you first.
But unfortunately he gave the same error again. 'The program stopped working.' I think there is a service overlap.